# Prime numbers in Jablon or Ford and Kaliski password authentication protocols?

Tags: passwords, cryptography, protocols, primes, password-encryption

As we can see in this [paper](http://www.jablon.org/jab01.pdf) about the **Jablon** protocol we use certain big prime numbers (**p,q,r**).

Were and how are these numbers stored?

Comment: This is not a programming question, if I'm not mistaken it belongs on http://crypto.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2):

The prime parameters p,q,r in section 4.2 are not assumed to be secret.

A primary goal of a "password-only multi-server roaming protocol" is that the password is the only credential (secret or otherwise) used by the client.  This implies that no other secrets are needed, and thus that no other implementation parameters need to be secret.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about this `Jablon` protocol and the paper is 16 pages long (I am not sure why you expect someone to read it...)
But just reading the preface and going to the conclusion I see (my emphasis):

> We've presented what appears to be the first description of a
>   password-only multi-server roaming protocol. It retrieves sensitive
>   data from multiple related credentials servers, without exposing the
>   password to off-line guessing **unless all servers are compromized**

So I guess these numbers you ask about are stored in different servers and using them you can reconstruct the secret. So to steal it one must break all servers.

Comment: Thanks anyway, I hoped that someone already familiar with this protocol would see this question.

Comment: @RexLakio:But have **you** read the paper?A really fast look I gave seemed that it is easy to read.

Comment: i did, a couple of times, it has no clear specification on were these prime numbers (parameters) should be stored, or if they represent an security problem if they are made public

Comment: Try one more time.I believe the idea is that they can be stored in HD since it is the overall deployment that ensures security.In the preface I skimmed it says smartcards are out of the question.Additionally I don't think the should be public since if they were, then what's the point of retrieving them after authenticating to the servers?

Comment: Actually the protocol says nothing about retrieving the prime numbers.  You have to retreive shares from each server to recreate your master key according to the password. But in order to do that you have to use   the prime numbers before the authentication.

Comment: Sorry I don't have time to read it.But I would suggest you ask this in Security SE